# How to use multiple optional parameter in Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-function-async

How to use multiple optional parameter in Azure function?
I am creating Azure function like this with one parameter, it is working.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRName(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get",  
            Route = "CommonResource/{subscriptionId?}")] HttpRequest req,
            string subscriptionId, 
            string resourcetype, 
            string location, 
            ILogger log)
        {
         ---
        }
```

If i add additional parameter like this getting an error.

```
[FunctionName("GetResourceName")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetRName(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get",  Route = "CommonResource/{subscriptionId:string?}/{resourcetype?}")] HttpRequest req,
            string subscriptionId ,string resourcetype , ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("This API should return Resource name.");

            //string resourcetype = req.Query["resourcetype"];
            resourcetype = req.Query["resourcetype"];
            string location = req.Query["location"];
```

Please check the attached screen shot for your referance.

[image]

Comment: What parameter you want to use?

Comment: I want to use resourcetype and location. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

> The constraint entry 'subscriptionId' - 'string' on the route 'api/CommonResource/{subscriptionId:string?}/{resourcetype?}' could not be resolved by the constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver'.

You are using `{subscriptionId:string?}` that is not supported, which cause the above error.

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints) lists the supported constraints, please refer to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you Route property

```
Route = "CommonResource/{subscriptionId:int}/{resourcetype}")
```

If you want to use multiple optional parameters, only consecutive parameters will work

```
Route = "CommonResource/{subscriptionId:int?}/{resourcetype?}")
```

Comment: I am getting an error when i add this code Route = "CommonResource/{subscriptionId:int?}/{resourcetype?}")